# DOTNET EF create your own custom command

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to extend

```
Dotnet ef migrations/database/dbcontext
```

to create our own commands?

If yes, how do we do it? I am looking for something like in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan where you can create your own command.

Basically, I want to create the command to seed my database. I am well aware that I can create a class that will seed data and can be called from startup class. I just want to know that if it is already available from the Entity Framework or not?

For example

```
dotnet ef migrations seed-data
```

where `seed-data` would be my custom command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it's possible to extend Migrations such as you want but I think a better approach is to create a DataSeeder class which will create/apply migrations and call it from Startup.cs like :

```
    public class DataSeeder
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public DataSeeder(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void MigrateDatabase()
        {
            _context.Migrate();
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs :

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DataSeeder dataSeeder)
        {
            //Bla bla your config
            ...
            dataSeeder.MigrateDatabase();
        }
```

***EDIT:***

You can extend CLI tools by three ways : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility#per-project-based-extensibility.

You have many samples here : https://github.com/natemcmaster/dotnet-tools.

But again, I Think you should use a common approach like I explain above. Specially for Migrations cause EF can have weird behavior if you change it.
You can try to twist EF like you want but it's better to understand how it works and think how can your code can works with it.

Comment: Yes, currently I am using this approach. I just wanted to know if creating a command is a common practice in asp.net or not.